# Can not connect to a postgres database in a docker container from my local machine

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a strange problem with docker and postgres. I can not connect from my local machine to psql inside the docker container.

First of all I created my container with this command: 
`docker run -d -p 5432:5432 --name my-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword postgres`

After that I executed the container with following command: 
`docker exec -it my-postgres bash`

Inside the container I started psql with the postgres user: 
`psql -U postgres` 
And I created a new database: 
`CREATE DATABASE mytestdb;`

Everything works inside the container, but if I want to connect to it from my machine it does only show the database from my machine. I tried this to connect to postgres: 
`psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres`

Which should me show something like this:

```
                                 List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------
 mytestdb  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)
```

But instead I get this:

```
                                          List of databases
      Name       |      Owner      | Encoding | Collate | Ctype   |        Access privileges          
-----------------+-----------------+----------+---------+---------+----------------------------------
 user            | user            | UTF8     | C       | C       | 
 postgres        | user            | UTF8     | C       | C       | 
 template0       | user            | UTF8     | C       | C       | =c/user                 +
                 |                 |          |         |         | user =CTc/user
 template1       | user            | UTF8     | C       | C       | =c/user                 +
                 |                 |          |         |         | user =CTc/user
(4 rows)

(END)
```

In every tutorial, I saw they did it, but for me, it doesn't work. So please help me.

Comment: Do `ss -tln` to find out who is listening port 5432 on your machine's interfaces.

Comment: This command does not work

Comment: Try `netstat -tln` then.
What OS are you running?

Comment: I'm running macOS. This command works and I get a lot of data back, but I don't understand it.

Comment: Do you have postgres installed in you machine ? try  to change the port and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when you creating the db.
`CREATE DATABASE mytestdb` you forgot to add `;` the command should be like `CREATE DATABASE mytestdb;`

And then you have your db and you can access it from inside the container or your host with these commands

Comment: I have already created the db, I just forgot the `;` in my question.

Comment: Could you try the same process with another port? 5000 for example:

`docker run -d -p 5000:5432 --name my-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword postgres`

And then on the host:
`psql -h localhost -p 5000 -U postgres`

Comment: the problem is not with the database creation as you can see it already retrieve the databases inside the container

Comment: Yes I saw that, what I am thinking is that maybe the port 5432 on your host is already listening to another db and this is what you see when you connect with `psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres`

Comment: @J-Mous it was the port. I changed it to 5000 and it worked. Thank you

Comment: But now I have another question. When I create a container on port 5432 why can't I see the db when I run `psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres`? Is it because my local postgres is connected to this port already?

Comment: Hello @Max happy to help, could you also upvote/accept my answer that helped you please? 

Regarding your question I am not really sure as I ll have to see what is running on your host, but yes most probably you have already something running on port 5432, I would guess another postgres, probably one that is not in a container?

Comment: @J-Mous, yes on port 5432 is running my local postgres. Thank you